# Changing string to capital letters function

Tags: c++

I'm dealing with some excercise, according to which I have to change string given on the input to the same string, written with capital letters.

Here's is my try, for some strange reason it prints out only the first word of string, it doesn't read the bit that is after space... 
Any ideas how to fix it ?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

void uppercase(string str)
{
   locale loc; 
   for(size_t i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
   {
      cout << toupper(str[i], loc); 
   } 
 } 

 int main(void)
 {
    string text; 
    cout << "Input text, please: " << endl;
    cin >> text; 
    uppercase(text); 
  }
```

I know that there might be different ways to solve this excersice, but I would like to stick with my method. Any potential mistakes ?

Comment: `while (cin >> text) uppercase(text);`

Comment: `cin >> text;` stops processing at the first white space.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, use `std::getline` to get a whole line instead of one word.  You should almost always use it, actually, because line-oriented is the way most programs take input.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from `std::cin` is space-delimited. In order to get the whole string up to a new-line, you want `std::getline`.

```
std::getline( std::cin, text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void uppercase(string str)
{
     locale loc; 
     for(size_t i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
     {
          if(str[i] != " ")
          {
               cout << toupper(str[i], loc); 
          }
     } 
}
```